# Magical Shield Sound in Slow Motion

Tags: sound-design

Hello Again,

I have a task were i have to create a "Magical Shield Sound". The animation here is @ slow motion.

So if any ideas kindly share it.

Cheers!!!

Comment: It depends on the animation & context. Provide more information.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see…based on the information you've provided I would use either a reversed dog bark, a filtered wave crash, or the sound of Saturn's rings as recorded by a deep space probe.

(That was sarcasm.)

If you want the sound design community to help you with ideas, you NEED TO PROVIDE MORE INFORMATION.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a chinese Gong layered with electrical discharges with lots of reverb .
Try to add a long swoosh with a long tail and sync the peak of that swoosh with the Gong.

cheers